# Jquery / Javascript check if input file is got files or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

//This is not a a duplicate question but what i need to do is check that a file input element has got files or not from anywhere in my javascript code without depending on built in events

**//forexample...**

```
$('input_element').change(function(event){
                    //code...
                    //any code here but
                    if(event.target.files.length>0){
                        //files around/selected
                    }else{
                        //code..
                        //files not around/selected
                    }
                })


                //But i need to check if files selected without that event ( anonymously... )
                //like

                if($('input_element').get(0).files.length>0){
                    //code
                    //here i get an error "can not read propert length of undefined!"
                    console.log('files are selected!')
                }else{
                    //code ...
                    //do something...
                }

            **//any help appreciated!**
```

Comment: `$('input_element').get(0).target.files.length` try

Comment: You could just move the even function outside of the listener. So you'd have `function check(){ /* ... */ } $('input_element').change(check); check();`

Comment: $('input_element').get(0).target.files.length is already there, it returns cant ready property length if undefine

Comment: It should be `$('input_element').get(0).files.length` without `.target` OR even shorter `$('input_element')[0].files.length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start off with a jQuery object e.g. `var $input = $(selector)`, you need to use its native HTML element using `$input[0]` to access its properties which contains a `files` array.

Below is a quick example:

```js
$(function() {
  var $input = $('[name=file]');
  $('button').click(function() {
    alert($input[0].files.length ? 'files were selected' : 'no files were selected');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="file" multiple><br><br>
<button>Check</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<input id="fileInput" type="file">
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('fileInput').files.length > 0 // will be true if there's a file
```